# Fastest way to find patterns in multivariate time series/matrix

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

patterns = ('a',[[1,2],[8,9]])

for pattern in patterns[1]:
    for x in a:
        for index in range(len(x)):
            if x[index:index+len(pattern)]==pattern:
                x[index:index+len(pattern)]=[patterns[0] for p in pattern]
```

This code finds multi-line patterns but does not take into account alignment of the patterns, nor that the complete pattern should be found before transforming anything within the matrix. But how to do that currently escapes me.

---

Formally the problem is as follows:

I have a matrix like

```
matrix=[
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]]
```

in which i want to find a pattern like

```
[1,2]
[any,5]
```

thus a pattern of [1,2] with in any row below, any value for the first value and a 5 for the second one.

```
or

[1]
[4]
```

thus a 1 and a 4 that are in the same column

```
or

[2,3]
[8,9]
```

thus 2 and 3 are adjacent within the row as well as 8 and 9, while 2 and 8 are in the same column and 3 and 9 are within the same column.

```
to transform the matrix into (given the first pattern and transforming it into 'a') 
output = [
[a,a,3],
[4,a,6],
[7,8,9]]
```

Now I have looked at the following questions:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952574/match-a-pattern-and-save-to-variable-using-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013618/find-pattern-in-matrix-made-of-lists-python-3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195572/find-all-indices-instances-of-all-repeating-patterns-across-columns-and-rows-of) however I am either not searching with the right keywords, or this question is new.

I myself would use something along the lines of

```
if matrix[index:index+len(pattern)]==pattern
```

with then extra tidbits to check in the lower rows once a pattern has been found however this is **far** too slow as the length of the rows is in the tens of thousands and the rows are almost in the thousand.

I need to repeat this search and replace operation many times over the same matrix, thus giving a matrix such as:

```
Given:
input = [
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[1,8,9]]
and
a=[[1,2,any],
   [any,8,9]]
b=[[3],
   [6]]
c=[[4,5],
   [1,any]]

Output = [
[a,a,b],
[c,c,b],
[c,a,a]]
```

Thank you for your attention and let me know if I formatted anything wrong it's my first post on Stack

Comment: This is a requirements dump. Please show what you've done, and use real notation, as what you currently have is ambiguous/nonsensical.

Comment: What do you mean by real notation that term sounds incredibly vague.

Comment: What is `[ ,5]`, for example?

Comment: Ah right, my bad I will replace that with an NA, I just didnt want them to misalign

Comment: Please write actual Python, and show your attempts

Comment: The output doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: The output in the last case doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to replace integers with references to lists?

Comment: I'd actually keep the patterns as the key in a dictionary and replace them with a character, which would be given as one of the values tied within the dictionary. It's just that this is as small and concrete as I can make the subproblem in my project. I could make it a tuple (i.e. patterns = ('a', [[1,2],[8,9]]) ) if thats clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach. This just tries to match one line of the pattern a time and if it succeeds moves to the next one until a total match is achieved. If that happens then it replaces the saved indexed with the replacement string passed.

```
def replace_pattern(matrix, pattern_list, replacement, start_row, col=None, idxs=[]):

    # if the pattern list is empty we found our pattern, lets replace the idxs
    if (pattern_list == []):
        replace_idx(matrix, replacement, idxs)
        return True

    n_rows = len(matrix)
    n_cols = len(matrix[0])
    pattern = pattern_list[0]
    pattern_size = len(pattern)

    # impossible to complete pattern if we have more lines remaining in the pattern than in the matrix
    if (start_row + len(pattern_list) > n_rows):
        return False

    for row in range(start_row, n_rows):
        # if we already found part of the pattern previously we only need to check a fixed position
        if col != None:
            new_idxs = idxs + [(row, filter_idx(pattern, col))]
            if match(matrix[row][col : (col + pattern_size)], pattern) and replace_pattern(matrix, pattern_list[1:], replacement, row + 1, col, new_idxs):
                return True
        # if we have not found part of the pattern yet, we can search in every position of the current line
        else:
            for pos in range(0, n_cols - pattern_size + 1):
                new_idxs = idxs + [(row, filter_idx(pattern, pos))]
                if match(matrix[row][pos : (pos + pattern_size)], pattern) and replace_pattern(matrix, pattern_list[1:], replacement, row + 1, pos, new_idxs):
                    return True
    return False
```

This function uses a few help functions:

this one determines if a pattern matches some values

```
def match(values, pattern):
    for i in range(len(values)):
        if values[i] == 'any' or pattern[i] == 'any':
            continue
        else:
            if values[i] != pattern[i]:
                return False
    return True
```

this one filters out the pattern indexes with 'any' since you don't want those cells replaced

```
def filter_idx(pattern, col):
    pattern_size = len(pattern)
    l = []
    for i in range(col, col + pattern_size):
        if pattern[i - col] != 'any':
            l.append(i)
    return l
```

This final one replaces pairs of (row, [cols]) with the replacement string passed.

```
def replace_idx(matrix, replacement, idxs):
    for entry in idxs:
        row = entry[0]
        for col in entry[1]:
            matrix[row][col] = replacement
```

Using the following inputs:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

pattern_a = [[1, 2, 'any'],['any', 8, 9]]
pattern_b =[[3], [6]]
pattern_c = [[4, 5], [7, 'any']]

replace_pattern(m, pattern_a, 'a', 0)
replace_pattern(m, pattern_b, 'b', 0)
replace_pattern(m, pattern_c, 'c', 0)
print(m)
```

I got the output:

```
[['a', 'a', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'b'], ['c', 'a', 'a']]
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you, really smart how you solved it. Now that I see it, it looks very simple but I was stuck on this for days so thanks again.